# 60GB HDD reports 2TB total size and 60GB partition

Tags: hard-drive

I recently got my hands on a falty external drive. The HDD inside the enclosure turned out to be 2.5 IDE Fujitsu MHT2060AH, and enclosure controller didn't seem to be giving any signs of life. I've connected the drive via run-of-the-mill 3-in-1 USB IDE/SATA adapter and Windows finally saw it. It wasn't working correctly, however - both Explorer and Drive Manager were frozing after trying to do anything with it. The only thing i could see is that drive was recognized as 2TB with a 60GB partition.

After fiddling around with different tools, i've managed to recover some data from drive with TestDisk (it actually errored after reading about 60GB, so i believe that i recovered all data i could). Now that i've got a backup, i thought that maybe there is a slight chance that drive could be restored, so i kept going.

Among other tools i tried, there was HDDScan, which returned this:
[image: Identity Report]

As far as i can understand, LBA28 sector count multiplied by sector size gives exactly 2TB. LBA48 is 0, but according to drive manual it should be supported. The label on a drive itself says LBA count should be 117210240.

Next I've boot up Knoppix and run a few `hdparm` commands (faulty drive is /dev/sde):

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 931.4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part 
sdc      8:32   1    15G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1    15G  0 part /mnt-system
sde      8:64   0     2T  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   0  55.9G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
cloop0 240:0    0   1.8G  1 disk /KNOPPIX
cloop1 240:1    0   9.6G  1 disk /KNOPPIX1
zram0  253:0    0   2.6G  0 disk [SWAP]

knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -g /dev/sde
/dev/sdb:
geometry = 4260880/16/63, sectors = 4294967294, start = 0

knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -g /dev/sde1
/dev/sdb1:
geometry = 116278/16/63, sectors = 117209169, start = 63

knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sde
/dev/sdf:
ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical         max     current
    cylinders       0       0
    heads           0       0
    sectors/track   0       0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0

knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sde1
/dev/sdf1:
ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical         max     current
    cylinders       0       0
    heads           0       0
    sectors/track   0       0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0

knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sde
/dev/sdf:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 0/1, HPA is enabled

knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sde1
/dev/sdf1:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 0/1, HPA is enabled
```

I'm not exactly sure what to make of it, but it looks to me that output from `sudo hdparm -g /dev/sde` and `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sde` is erroneous.

So, given all that, is there anything else that i can try?

**Update 25.07.2021:**
Okay, 3.5 to 2.5 IDE adapter finally arrived and it certainly made difference - here's what `hdparm` ouputs now (faulty drive is now /dev/sda):

```
noppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -g /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 geometry      = 267349/255/63, sectors = 4294967294, start = 0


knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -g /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
 geometry      = 7295/255/63, sectors = 117209169, start = 63


knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       FUJITSU MHT2060AH                       
        Serial Number:      NP05T4B26LBV
        Firmware Revision:  006C    
Standards:
        Used: ATA/ATAPI-6 T13 1410D revision 3a 
        Supported: 6 5 4 
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:  4294967294
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     2097151 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     2199023 MBytes (2199 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes (type=DualPortCache)
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(cannot be disabled)
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
        Advanced power management level: 128
        Recommended acoustic management value: 254, current value: 254
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 *udma4 udma5 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=240ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
                Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    Automatic Acoustic Management feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
        not     supported: enhanced erase
        60min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
HW reset results:
        CBLID- above Vih
        Device num = 0 determined by the jumper
Checksum: correct
// Same for sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda1


knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 4294967294/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
// Again, same for sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda1
```

**Update 30.08.2021:**
Again from a backburner. Tried setting max sectors via -Np now (for /dev/sda1 as well):

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing -Np117210240 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting max visible sectors to 117210240 (permanent)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 e6 01 21 04 00 00 00 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 4294967294/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

Is there anything else that i can try?

Comment: _"maybe there is a slight chance that drive could be restored"_ - it's too old to be reliable and too small to be useful. If you need it for retro hardware restoration, consider an SD card to ATA adapter instead. And if you want to give it a try just for the sake of it, try with another adapter. This one may be lying.

Comment: Have you tried a _different_ USB-IDE adapter?

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about getting a 3.5 to 2.5 IDE adapter (i guess it's as dumb piece of hardware as it could get), but it might take a while to get my hands on it.

Comment: @user1686, it arrived, i've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The
[FUJITSU MHT2060AH](https://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=FUJITSU%20MHT2060AH)
has as disk interface the old Ultra-ATA/100, not modern IDE.

I think the problem is with the connector you used. You might need
a connector such as
[PSATA IDE Ultra ATA 100/133 to SATA Converter Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003AG5CN6).

The disk itself is truly 60 GB, so might not be worth the investment.

Comment: Yeah, it seems USB adapter just didn't cut it. ATA adapter arrived, so i've updated my question.